# C++ memory allocation upon resizing of reserved std::vector

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I am curious about the std::vector behavior and I could not find answer anywhere, so ...

Lets have an odd program:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(5);
for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) // OK, I have noticed the mistake in the condition, I am leaving it here for educational purposes
{
    vec.resize(vec.size() + 1);
    vec[i] = 42;
}
```

What the behavior in terms of memory allocations will be? Only one allocation upon memory reserving as expected, or resizing clears the memory it does not need?

Comment: erm... maybe you want to rethink that question. There is only two memory allocations taking place. One when you create the vector and one when you reserve. Since the size of the vector is `0` the loop wont do anything at all

Comment: The loop is never entered.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong condition in the for. I realize it now. Nevertheless, the question remains.

Comment: @tobi303  No, Aside from a required fix to execute the loop at all, there is no memory allocation when the vector is created. However, when the size becomes non zero and as the size is increased there will be occasional memory allocations and moving of the contents after the size goes beyond 5. When depends on the standard library design.

Comment: @doug actually I wasnt sure, now I checked and it seems like the standard does not specifiy the capacity of a newly created vector. Most implementations provide zero capacity, but anything else is also possible

Comment: @tobi303 - It might be legal but, given how common running `reserve()` after instantiating a default `vector<T>` where the size, or max size is known is, I can't imagine any std designer doing so. I use that sequence fairly often and have never encountered that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters this loop will be executed never

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(5);
for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
{
    vec.resize(vec.size() + 1);
    vec[i] = 42;
}
```

because initially the size of the vector is equal to 0.

Maybe you mean something like the following

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(5);
for(int i = 0; i < vec.capacity(); ++i)
{
    vec.resize(vec.size() + 1);
    vec[i] = 42;
}
```

In this case the vector will not be reallocated.:)

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 5;

    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve( N );

    std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0;

    do
    {
        v.resize( v.size() + 1);
        std::cout << v.capacity() << '\t' << v.data() << std::endl;
    } while ( ++i < v.capacity() );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
5   0x824da10
5   0x824da10
5   0x824da10
5   0x824da10
5   0x824da10
```

Answer (score 1):

What the [`reserve`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) method actually does is:

> Requests that the [*vector capacity*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/) be at least enough to contain `n` elements.
>
> - If `n` is greater than the current [*vector capacity*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/), the function causes the container to reallocate its storage increasing its *capacity* to `n` (or greater).
> - In all other cases, the function call does not cause a reallocation and the *vector capacity* is not affected.
> - This function has no effect on the [*vector size*](http://www.cplusplus.com/vector::size) and cannot alter its elements.

So, at first, `vec.reserve(5);` will allocate memory for `5` elements. (But the *vector size* will still be `0`)

Then, inside loop, you are calling `vec.resize(vec.size() + 1);`, let's first have a look, what does this function do:

What [`resize`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) actually do is:

> Resizes the container so that it contains n elements.
>
> - If `n` is smaller than the current container [*size*](http://www.cplusplus.com/vector::size), the content is reduced to its first `n` elements, removing those beyond (and destroying them).
> - If `n` is greater than the current *container size*, the content is expanded by inserting at the end as many elements as needed to reach a *size* of `n`. If `val` is specified, the new elements are initialized as copies of `val`, otherwise, they are value-initialized.
> - If `n` is also greater than the current container *capacity*, an automatic reallocation of the allocated storage space takes place.
> - Notice that this function changes the actual content of the container by inserting or erasing elements from it.

In your case, the program, in loop is always passing the `n` which is lower than the *`capacity`* of `vec`, so, no memory allocations will be performed, and only the *`size`* attribute will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

`reserve` allocates space to hold the requested number of items.
`resize` tells the vector how many items are currently in the container.

So if you reserve less then you specify with `resize` an allocation will occur. If you reserve more than you resize to, the subsequent resize doesn't require additional allocations.

Answer (score 0):

`vec.size()` is 0 to begin with. `vec.reserve(5)` will allocate space for at least 5 elements. Your loop will then do nothing.

But let's assume that you meant to loop to 5 instead. Only the reserve call will allocate more memory to the vector. The resizes inside the loop, since they are less than or equal to the capacity of the vector, will only construct new elements in the already allocated space.

Comment: `size != capacity` I would expect any decent compiler to reserve at least some space even if the size is 0

Comment: @tobi303 the capacity of a newly created std::vector is 0 in every implementation I've ever seen, probably on the if-you-don't-ask-for-it-then-you-don't-get-it principle that is so very common in c/c++.

Comment: you might be correct, I just wanted to point out that `vec.size() == 0` isnt that relevant for how many allocations took place. Maybe a bit too much nitpicking ;)